# if meta tags won't work on permalink (tumblr)

Tags: html, tumblr, meta

I have a problem which I can't for the life of me understand. I'm using if meta tags in my code so that I can choose whether I want to show tags and permalinks or not and for some reason, the meta tag works perfectly on the tags, but not on the permalinks (it simply hides the permalinks and can't show them at all).

```
<meta name="if:Show Permalink" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Show Tags" content="0" />

{block:IfShowPermalink}
<div id="permalink">
{block:NoteCount}
<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}</a>
{block:ContentSource}
<span style="font-size:8px">/</span> <a href="{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
{/block:ContentSource}
</div>
{/block:IfShowPermalink}

{block:IfShowTags}
<div id="tags">
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags} <a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}
</div>
{/block:IfShowTags}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I believe you are closing the permalink anchor too soon:

```
{block:IfShowPermalink}
<div id="permalink">
  {block:NoteCount}
  <a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
  {/block:NoteCount}
  {block:ContentSource}
  <span style="font-size:8px">/</span> <a href="{SourceURL}">{SourceTitle}</a>
  {/block:ContentSource}
</div>
{/block:IfShowPermalink}
```